# Quebrar um inteiro em pequenas partes em Java

Tags: java

Preciso colocar cada dígito de um inteiro em uma posição de um vetor.

```
int a = 123;
List<Integer> numerosGerados = new ArrayList<>();
```

E agora preciso colocar o número 1 na posição 0 do *array*, o número 2 na 1 e assim por diante. O número pode ser negativo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033550/convert-integer-to-array-of-digits

Comment: Você precisa de um método aritmético, tal como [nessa sua outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53055/215), ou um envolvendo strings basta? Um pouco mais de contexto ajudaria, por exemplo se isso é algum exercício ou se é para se usar na prática (e se for na prática, para que).

Comment: "E no caso de o número ser negativo" ... O que acontece? Ignora o sinal de menos, dá um erro ou você tem que colocar o sinal de menos na lista? Se for a última opção então complicou, pois o sinal de menos sozinho não é um inteiro.

Comment: Exato, estou em dúvida em relação a isto também.

Comment: @DanLucioPrada Veja se a minha resposta te serve, senão explique melhor o que você quer fazer com os números negativos.

Comment: @DanLucioPrada Sendo que o número `123` é equivalente a `100*1 + 10*2 + 1*3`, o `-123` é equivalente a `100*(-1) + 10*(-2) + 1*(-3)`, de modo que uma opção é fazer com que todos os "dígitos" sejam negativos. Outra opção é simplesmente "marcar" o número como negativo, mudando o primeiro dígito somente (como feito pelo Victor e por mim nas nossas respostas). De novo, pergunto, qual a finalidade disso?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Resposta baseada na do mgibsonbr, mas sem precisar inverter a lista:

```
int a = 123;
List<Integer> numerosGerados = new ArrayList<>();

int x = a > 0 ? a : -a;
do {
    numerosGerados.add(0, x % 10);
    x /= 10;
} while (x > 0);

if (a < 0) numerosGerados.set(0, -numerosGerados.get(0));
```

Se o número dado for negativo, o primeiro elemento da lista também será negativo.

Comment: A propósito, sua resposta é melhor que a minha, eu que tenho essa mania de "inserir no início da lista é ineficiente" - quando na realidade o tamanho das entradas é tão pequeno que não deve fazer muita diferença... (exceto se esse código for usado um número muito grande de vezes, é claro)

Comment: @mgibsonbr pelo menos temos 4 soluções diferentes :) e concordo que é a melhor até agora.

Answer (score 6):

Resolvendo matematicamente:

```
import java.util.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        ImprimeLista(SeparaDigitos(12345));
        ImprimeLista(SeparaDigitos(-123));
        ImprimeLista(SeparaDigitosNegativo(-123));
        ImprimeLista(SeparaDigitosNegativo(123));
    }
    public static List<Integer> SeparaDigitos(int valor) {
        List<Integer> numerosGerados = new ArrayList<>();
        int positivo = Math.abs(valor);
        int tamanho = (int)(Math.log10(positivo) + 1);
        int posicao = 0;
        while(posicao < tamanho) {
            int digito = valor / (int)Math.pow(10, tamanho - posicao - 1) * Integer.signum(valor);
            numerosGerados.add(digito);
            valor %= digito * Math.pow(10, tamanho - posicao - 1);
            posicao++;
        }
        return numerosGerados;
    }
    public static List<Integer> SeparaDigitosNegativo(int valor) {
        List<Integer> numerosGerados = new ArrayList<>();
        int positivo = Math.abs(valor);
        int tamanho = (int)(Math.log10(positivo) + 1);
        int posicao = 0;
        while(posicao < tamanho) {
            int digito = valor / (int)Math.pow(10, tamanho - posicao - 1) * (posicao == 0 ? 1 : Integer.signum(valor));
            numerosGerados.add(digito);
            valor %= digito * Math.pow(10, tamanho - posicao - 1);
            posicao++;
        }
        return numerosGerados;
    }
    public static void ImprimeLista(List<Integer> lista) {
        for (int item : lista) {
            System.out.println(item);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zGi0EK). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/txzbfeoy-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/SplitNumber.java).

Coloquei duas formas de tratar negativo, uma que ignora o sinal e outra que considera o sinal no primeiro dígito.

Comment: Neste caso, só funciona para números positivos, editei minha pergunta especificando que necessitar ser tanto positivo quanto negativo.

Comment: Esses requisitos são meio esquisitos e nunca são bem definidos, eu tratei como eu acho que dá para tratar os negativos na forma apresentada, provavelmente isto não faz muito sentido. Você precisa informar melhor o que está fazendo, qual o objetivo disto, caso contrário provavelmente essas suas perguntas vão gerar discussões no http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com para decidir o que fazer com elas. Se precisar que o negativo seja tratado diferente dá para fazer mas você precisa explicar de onde vem esses requisitos.

Answer (score 4):

Esse é um caso em que é mais fácil obter os dígitos na ordem inversa, e depois inverter a lista. Pois para se pegar o último dígito de um inteiro positivo basta fazer o resto da divisão por 10:

```
int a = -123;
List<Integer> numerosGerados = new ArrayList<>();

boolean negativo = (a < 0);
int x = negativo ? -a : a;
do {
    numerosGerados.add(x % 10);
    x /= 10;
} while (x > 0);
Collections.reverse(numerosGerados); // Inverte a lista

if ( negativo ) {
    // ??? (não dá pra colocar um "-" numa lista de inteiros...)

    // Exemplo: faz com que o primeiro deles seja negativo
    int primeiro = numerosGerados.get(0);
    numerosGerados.set(0, -primeiro);
}
```

Resultado: `[-1,2,3]`

Answer (score 3):

```
int value = 12345;
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<>();

for(char each : Integer.toString(value).toCharArray())
   array.add(Integer.parseInt(Character.toString(each)));
```

<kbd>[Exemplo funcionando no Ideone](http://ideone.com/qtd3z7)</kbd>